# How to save a checkbox value when click a save button in ios

Tags: ios

I have a check box designed through a button and i am able to change the checkbox images but i am unable to save that last image that is checked in the checkbox when i click on Save button.

I have a page in which a check box is there and save button action is also there when i click on save the value in the checkbox must be saved and when i again re-enter in that screen the previous whatever the value in the checkbox must be seen, but for me every time when i enter into this screen the checkbox is seen empty.

Hope someone helps me out.

```
BOOL checked;  

- (IBAction)canFollowAction:(id)sender
{
UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]])
{
    [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}


- (IBAction)btnSaveAction:(id)sender
{
if(checked)
{
    [btnCheckCanFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [btnCheckCanFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[[[iToast makeText:@"Successfully Updated"]setGravity:iToastGravityBottom]show];
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit using code or screen shot of what your trying to accomplish

Comment: This is my code can you work me out for the exact code, since i am very new to this iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Must Save the state in NSUSERDEFAULTS!

For Example ON Button Click

```
if (button.selected)
{
    [button setSelected:YES];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"REMEMBER_ME"];
}
```

and check on ViewDidLoad

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"REMEMBER_ME"] == YES)
{
   [button setSelected:YES];
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
else
{
  [button setSelected:NO];
  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"REMEMBER_ME"] == YES) that invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')

Comment: i have successfully implement this thing in my Project!

Comment: set selected.png for UIControlStateSelected   And checkBox.png for UIControlStateNormal in XIB!

Comment: You Are Always WelCome!

Comment: Now i have 3 checkboxes with three different actions and a save button now what i need to do.

Comment: just Save the boolean with Different Key!   1.Remember_1 2.Remember_2 3.Remember_3 etc....

Comment: ok thank you can you please give your email id i am new to this iOS development if any doubts are there i can consult you, if you don't mind aa.

Comment: sorry but i m also new to ios! i just used this method so i had helpd you! don't mind!

Answer (score 1):

@kool kims - The term you used Save value. There any many ways to keep persistent data of your application.

1. Use `NSUserDefaults` to save values at application level.
2. Use `.plist` file
3. CoreData
4. SQlite
5. Document directory

As per your application architecture you can choose from above, which is more relevant and efficient for your application.

**EDIT:**

The simplest way if there are not more than one checkbox, You can use `NSUserDefaults`

Save check value when you click on Save button

```
- (IBAction)btnSaveAction:(id)sender
{

    NSNumber *checkValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:checked];
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardDefaults setObject:checked forKey:@"kCheckBoxValue"];
    [standardDefaults synchronize];

    if(checked)
    {
        [btnCheckCanFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnCheckCanFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [[[iToast makeText:@"Successfully Updated"]setGravity:iToastGravityBottom]show];
}
```

Whenever you open that ViewController you get previous values from `NSUserDefaults` from `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([standardDefaults objectForKey:@"kCheckBoxValue"]) {
        NSNumber *checkValue = [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"kCheckBoxValue"];
        checked = [checkValue boolValue];
    } else {
        checked = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give any relevant code for NSUserDefaults to save that value.

Comment: If there are more than 1 check box then what is the scenario.

Comment: @koolkims: Create an `NSArray` which contains dictionary for above `NSNumber` values and than save it to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a global variable to strore the status of check box or in NSUserdefaults u can save the status of button. & chek this status on viewdidload method of controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood Lets take an example

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;
```

and its Implementation Action

```
- (IBAction)yourMethodName:(UIButton *)sender {

      int tag=_yourButton.tag; //if you have tagged your UI button save it to know which button has changed its state.

    if(sender.isSelected){ //Checking state of the button whether selected or not.

        UIImage *buttonImage=sender.currentImage;//save this image if your selected images randomly.
        NSString *buttonText=sender.currentTitle;//gets you current text in button.

    }else{
        //selected state is NO
        //checkBox is Off.
    }
}
```

here I have showed how you can get different values you need only to store your state as I believe your working with one button/checkbox and you can populate your image based on that state.

However if you have multiple checkboxes or UIbutton you may want to Tag each UIButton your using

```
[_yourButton setTag:1];
```

and store tag value too inside action method using `sender.tag`

**EDIT:**
Just now went through your code 
`BOOL checked;`  value is never set or stored.
so everytime if condition fails.

Also If you have multiple UIButtons you may want to store checked state and tag for the UIButton as I have mentioned earlier;